# mysql.connector are suddenly missing

Tags: python

```
import mysql.connector
```

Python is suddenly giving me a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rasmus\workspace\Python\src\First.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I have not touched my code since it were working. It was a very simple insert query. But I'm wondering how my mysql.connector suddenly are "gone". seems odd that the import statement was working lately and now it does not.

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: Do you have more than one version of Python installed? The `mysql.connector` package might only be installed in one Python distribution's site-packages...